# sudo permission inside docker container for jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I had created a Jenkinsfile using declarative syntax to build my nodejs application. I had used a docker agent to build, now its giving me permission error. This is my sample Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker { 
            image 'node:8.4'
              }
         }   
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                    sh 'pwd'
                    sh 'npm --version'
                    sh 'npm --prefix ./Server install'
            }
          }
        }
}

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
```

I had even tried to add the sudo command

```
 sh 'sudo npm --version'
```

but then it gives me no sudo found error. How can we give permission inside the docker from the Jenkinsfile, the current unix user is jenkins which I have added to the sudoers also. When i run the Jenkins file i can see it passes the jenkins user and group to the docker using -u option.

```
 docker run -t -d -u 109:116 -w /var/lib/jenkins/testapp
```

Comment: Can you run a `id && ls -alh` in the job and attach the output to your question

Comment: When i have given id && ls -alh this are the results i got                              
********
+ id
uid=109 gid=116 groups=116
********
 + ls -alh
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x  5  109  116 4.0K Sep  9 08:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Sep  9 18:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8  109  116 4.0K Sep  9 18:02 .git
-rw-r--r--  1  109  116  585 Sep  9 08:08 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  3  109  116 4.0K Sep  9 08:08 Client
-rw-r--r--  1  109  116  208 Sep  9 08:08 Jenkinsfile
drwxr-xr-x 13  109  116 4.0K Sep  9 08:08 Server
******

Answer (score 7):

Problem is related to npm trying to write its cache on /.npm folder. Since you are running your container with the -u flag, the user you run it is not root (the default). On a Linux machine, by default, non root users cannot create a new directory in /.

You have a few options to solve your problem:

1. Running your container as root by removing the -u option (this means that npm would be run by root user, this could lead to security problems)
2. Changing npm cache path to a folder where the unprivileged users can write such as /tmp
3. Use a custom docker image instead of the default node one where you create the /.npm directory and give write permissions to unprivileged users.

In my opinion option 2 is the easiest, just run this command before npm install in your build script:

```
export HOME=/tmp ;  npm config set cache /tmp
```

Also, npm stores its config into user's home directory. Since the user you are using doesn't exists in the container, their home directory is set to / . In order to avoid having write permission error, try setting the HOME env variable to /tmp too. Your install command becomes:

```
export HOME=/tmp ;  npm --prefix ./Server install
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, I checked your second option, by adding config to /tmp, but then it arises  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.npmrc' error. I think for all the folders i need to give the permission. So how can we make it run as root inside the docker, docker -u command is given by the Jenkins,

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me, although I needed to `export HOME` first as npm complained about trying to write to `/.npmrc` when adding the config.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the `npm config` command to also specify the HOME variable